# How do I assign specific numbers to specific letters?

Tags: java

I'm super new to Java and haven't learned a lot in class yet, but I was trying to write a program that would convert numbers into letters and then output the conversion to the console. I have specific numbers that I need to assign to the letters so I can't use the Java default ones. I used switch statements to assign the numbers so far but it only allows me to input one at a time before I have to run the program again. I want to be able to type series of numbers before getting the answer. For example, in my case "A" = 21 "C" = 23 "D" = 31 etc, so there isn't necessarily a pattern.

Essentially I just want to know if it is possible to input a series of specific numbers (example: 42 32 93) and get the corresponding output (H E Y)

This is what I have so far, but I'm not sure if there is a more efficient way to do this or what to do next. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumbersToLetters 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // Declaration section                
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = 0;
        char letter = 0;

        // Prompts the user for input
        System.out.println("Enter the numbers: ");

        number = scan.nextInt();

        // Assigns letters to the number variables
        switch (number) 
        {
            case 21:
                letter = 'A';
                break;
            case 22:
                letter = 'B';
                break;
            case 23:
                letter = 'C';
                break;
            case 31:
                letter = 'D';
                break;
            case 32:
                letter = 'E';
                break;
            case 33:
                letter = 'F';
                break;
            case 41:
                letter = 'G';
                break;
            case 42:
                letter = 'H';
                break;
            case 43:
                letter = 'I';
                break;
            case 51:
                letter = 'J';
                break;
            case 52:
                letter = 'K';
                break;
            case 53:
                letter = 'L';
                break;
            case 61:
                letter = 'M';
                break;
            case 62:
                letter = 'N';
                break;
            case 63:
                letter = 'O';
                break;
            case 71:
                letter = 'P';
                break;
            case 72:
                letter = 'Q';
                break;
            case 73:
                letter = 'R';
                break;
            case 74:
                letter = 'S';
                break;
            case 81:
                letter = 'T';
                break;
            case 82:
                letter = 'U';
                break;
            case 83:
                letter = 'V';
                break;
            case 91:
                letter = 'W';
                break;
            case 92:
                letter = 'X';
                break;
            case 93:
                letter = 'Y';
                break;
            case 94:
                letter = 'Z';
                break;
            default: System.out.println("Enter a valid value");

        } // END OF switch()

        System.out.print(letter);
        System.out.println();

    } // END OF main() method

} // END OF DRIVER CLASS
```

Comment: Maybe using a while loop ?

Answer (score 0):

I offer you to use `Map`. This is more readable. You have to define it only once and use it every time. But comareing performance, this does not give any profit. So and your and my apporahc work fine, difference is in visual and support (someone think that using `if...else` and `switch` are not ture OOP :-)).

```
public final class NumbersToLetters implements Function<Integer, Character> {

    private static final Map<Integer, Character> MAP = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        MAP.put(21, 'A');
        MAP.put(22, 'B');
        MAP.put(23, 'C');
        MAP.put(31, 'D');
        MAP.put(32, 'E');
        MAP.put(33, 'F');
        MAP.put(41, 'G');
        MAP.put(42, 'H');
        MAP.put(43, 'I');
        MAP.put(51, 'J');
        MAP.put(52, 'K');
        MAP.put(53, 'L');
        MAP.put(61, 'M');
        MAP.put(62, 'N');
        MAP.put(63, 'O');
        MAP.put(71, 'P');
        MAP.put(72, 'Q');
        MAP.put(73, 'R');
        MAP.put(74, 'S');
        MAP.put(81, 'T');
        MAP.put(82, 'U');
        MAP.put(83, 'V');
        MAP.put(91, 'W');
        MAP.put(92, 'X');
        MAP.put(93, 'Y');
        MAP.put(94, 'Z');
    }

    @Override
    public Character apply(Integer num) {
        return MAP.getOrDefault(num, '\0');
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Function<Integer, Character> numberToLetter = new NumbersToLetters();

        System.out.println(numberToLetter.apply(42));
        System.out.println(numberToLetter.apply(32));
        System.out.println(numberToLetter.apply(93));
    }

}
```

Comment: also mentioning that a map is `amortized O(1)` for lookups is important

Answer (score 0):

To ease readability, I've omitted the huge `switch` body. There's nothing wrong with it (though there are other ways to accomplish the same thing), it just isn't really relevant to the actual question.

> ```
> public static void main(String[] args) 
> {
>     // Declaration section                
>     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
>     int number = 0;
>     char letter = 0;
>
>     // Prompts the user for input
>     System.out.println("Enter the numbers: ");
>
>     number = scan.nextInt();
>
>     // Assigns letters to the number variables
>     switch (number) 
>     {
>         // letter = something
>     }
>
>     System.out.print(letter);
>     System.out.println();
>
> }
> ```

The problem here is that the program will just run through what you're doing until it finishes, and there's nothing inside `main()` that tells the program to allow the user to input more than one number.

You have a couple of options. One is that you could prompt the user for multiple numbers at once (by replacing `number = scan.nextInt()` with something like:

```
String input = scan.nextLine();
String[] numbers = input.split(" ");

for (String number : numbers) {
    int asInt = Integer.parseInt(number);

    // your switch logic here, plus printing out the letters
}
```

Another option is to just repeat what you're doing until the user manually exits the program. You'd accomplish that by wrapping what you have in a `while (true)` loop:

```
while (true) {
    number = scan.nextInt();

    // Assigns letters to the number variables
    switch (number) 
    {
        // letter = something
    }

    System.out.print(letter);
    System.out.println();
}
```

There are many other ways to do approximately the same thing. The important concept is to add a *loop* of some sort to your program so that the code can be executed more than once.

Comment: I tried out that first suggestion that you gave, however it keeps saying that the variable numbers is already defined in the main method, and when I try to run it, it throws an exception